# Plot DataFrame in 1 year period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have dataframe:

```
                    temp_old                                            temp_new
Year                2013        2014    2015    2016    2017    2018    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018
Date                                                

2013-01-01 23:00:00 21.587569   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2013-01-02 00:00:00 21.585347   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2013-01-02 01:00:00 21.583472   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2018-02-05 00:00:00 NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     22.882083
2018-02-05 01:00:00 NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     22.878472
```

When I plot this df thats my result.

[image]

My goal is show it but without separate by years. So I want to have 5 curves in range January: December on one chart.

update:(code to plot)

```
df_sep_by_year.plot(figsize=(15,8))
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove year from your Date column? I mean instead of *2013-01-01 23:00:00* use *01-01 23:00:00* and adjust your data similarly for other records.

Comment: Agreed. Unless there's a nice way of using groupby, the simple solution is to create a column without the year and plot each of the years on the same figure.

Comment: I think this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44001887/6361531).  Create columns of years, with the index as dayofyear.  The use df.plot to plot the columns as series with the x-axis as day of year from 1 to 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove year from your Date column. I mean instead of **2013-01-01 23:00:00** use **01-01 23:00:00** and adjust your data similarly for other records.

```
# remove datetime index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
# create new column without year, use ':02d' to correct sorting
df['new_date'] = df.Date.apply(lambda x: '{:02d}-{:02d}-{:02d}:00:00'.format(x.month, x.day, x.hour)) 
# set new index to df
df.set_index('new_date', inplace=True)
# remove old column with datetime
df = df.drop(labels=['Date'], axis=1)
# remove multiindex in columns
df.columns = [''.join(str(col)) for col in df.columns]
# join variable from different year but the same month and day
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[x]).dropna(axis=0, how='any') for x in df_sep_by_year], axis=1).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df.plot()
```